# Get results from multiple tables after grouping using Linq-to-SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, linq-to-sql, group-by, where-clause

I think the answer should be easy, but I'm just struggling:

Would like to have data from 2 tables in a LINQ query similar to:

```
from f in Faults
join af in AvailabilityFaults on f.FaultID equals af.FaultID
join a in Availabilities on new { af.CalendarDay, af.CircuitNumber}
             equals new { a.CalendarDay, a.CircuitNumber}
join e in ExternalImportAvailabilities on new { a.CalendarDay, a.CircuitNumber }
                   equals new { e.CalendarDay, e.CircuitNumber }
where a.CalendarDay.Value.Day != 1
group f by f.FaultID into groupF
select new {groupF, e.CalendarDay}
```

The problem here comes in that it can't find `e.CalendarDay` in the select clause.

I also tried things like: `CalendarDay= e.Max(e=>e.CalendarDay)`, but e is not in the current context.

How can I add data from table 'e' in the select clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you properly, this is what you are looking for:

```
from f in Faults
join af in AvailabilityFaults on f.FaultID equals af.FaultID
join a in Availabilities on af.CalendarDay equals a.CalendarDay and af.CircuitNumber equals a.CircuitNumber
join e in ExternalImportAvailabilities on a.CalendarDay equals e.CalendarDay and a.CircuitNumber equals e.CircuitNumber
where a.CalendarDay.Value.Day != 1
group new {f, e} by f.FaultID into groupFE
select new {GroupF = groupFE.Select( gfe => gfe.f), CalendarDay = groupFE.Max( gfe => gfe.e.CalendarDay)}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like you only changed the syntax of the joins. The syntax of your joins does not work though.
If I remove the group clause, then it works, but adding the group causes the problem.

Comment: Nice work.  It works (with my old joins, but your select and join), Well Done

Answer (score 0):

If you want e.CalendarDay in your select, then you normally would include it in the group, as in

```
group f by new { f.FaultID , e.CalendarDay } into groupF
select new {groupF.Key.FaultID, groupF.Key.CalendarDay}
```